# My drop down menu is hidden behind my section tag

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

My drop down menu is hidden behind my "mainsection" tag and I'm not sure what I can do to expose it. It needs to lay on top of the "mainsection" tag area and not behind it.

Here is the jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/nSmZ9/

and here is the html code

```
<header>
<ul class="right-nav-after-login">
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>
        Menu
        <ul>
            <li>Account</li>
            <li>My Gifts</li>
            <li>Log off</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Contact</li>
</ul>
</header>
<article>
    <section class="mainsection"></section>
</article>
```

here is my css

```
header {
    height: 66px;
    margin-left: 75px;
    margin-right: 75px;
    border: 2px solid black;

}

.mainsection {
    background-color: #a6dbed;
    height: 500px;
    position: relative;
}

.right-nav-after-login {
    float: right;
  text-align: left;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px 4px 17px 0;
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
.right-nav-after-login li {
  font: bold 12px/18px sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  background: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
.right-nav-after-login li:hover {
  background: #555;
  color: #fff;
}
.right-nav-after-login li ul {
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 48px;
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -transition: opacity 0.2s;
}
.right-nav-after-login li ul li { 
  background: #555; 
  display: block; 
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
}
.right-nav-after-login li ul li:hover { background: #666; }
.right-nav-after-login li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.mainsection` is defined later in your HTML than the menu, and since both are taken out of the regular flow, `.mainsection` will cover the menu . I'd recommend a more natural layout but lacking that, you can try this:

```
.right-nav-after-login, .right-nav-after-login * {
    z-index: 1;
}
```

This will *guarantee* the menu and everything within to be above everything else, as long as the elements have `position` set to anything except `static`.

Comment: Hi, thanks! What would be a more natural flow? I'm kind of a newbie to css and html.

Comment: @user1186050: Just use the properties of block-level elements instead of magic numbers and weird floats and `position`s. (BTW, you can center a block-level element horizontally with `margin: 0 auto`).

Comment: can you give me any examples? I'm not really sure what you mean by magic numbers and weird floats.

Comment: @user1186050: Don't use `margin` with `75px` to center something, instead *say* that you want it centered with `margin: 0 auto`. By weird floats I mean unnecessarily using the `float` property. And this thread is getting off-topic; ask another question if you want more info.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `z-index` to specify the vertical stack order of elements. (*Note that in order for `z-index` to work, an element must have absolute or relative positioning.*)

There are different ways to do this. You just need to ensure that the element you want on top has a higher `z-index`. Here is one solution:

```
.mainsection {
    ....
    z-index:1;
}

.right-nav-after-login li ul li {
    ....
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
}
```

[**See demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/nSmZ9/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Take this off of .mainsection.

```
position: relative;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//inset this code
 .right-nav-after-login li ul{z-index:100;}
```